# Can Some one please explain how does this code work?

Tags: flutter, dart

[VS CODE IMAGE -  I want to understand the if statement and for loop part of this code , can somebody please elaborate this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86zDa.png)

Comment: I know there's a more easy and better way of doing the same task, but still, I want to understand this.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop takes the `number` passed and checks if it is divisible (by checking if the remainder of the division is 0) by each number starting from 2. If it is divisible by a number, the returned value `isPrime` is set to `false`, otherwise `isPrime` will remain `true` and it will be returned. The `for` loop stops at the square root of the number passed.

I.e., if the number 17 is passed as argument, it will be divided by 2, by 3 and by 4. It will return `true` because none of the values assumed by `i` gave a remainder of 0 in the division.
If the number 26 is passed, it will be divided by each integer up to 5, and the function will return `false` because the remainder of the division by 2 is 0.

Answer (score 0):

dart will execute the code that is inside void main() {}.
Inside main() there are 2 functions.

1. isNumberDivisible: This function takes 2 integers *number* and *divisor* and returns a bool value. The logic of the function is that, if the *number* is dividable with the *divisor* then it will return true. if not, it will return false.
2. isPrime: This function takes an integer *number* and returns a bool value. The logic of the function is, if the *number* is a prime it returns true, if not it will return false. The way it determines whether it is a prime is by checking if the the testing value: *number* is not dividable with every value until the root of *number* (using the function isNumberDivisible). (for example, if you want to test if 100 is a prime, you only have to check if it is not dividable with 2 to 10.)

Lastly, you are calling the isPrime function and testing the value 6 whether it is a prime. which should return false.